# Kendo UI Not Working with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, kendo-ui

I'm attempting to get a simple MultiSelect working in Meteor. After checking out ~20 different UI libraries, I decided Kendo UI looked best.

I looked around and found that they had Meteor package already set up to (supposedly) easily use Kendo UI in Meteor. Here's the steps I did to try and get a kind of Hello World with MultiSelect using Kendo UI in Meteor:

```
meteor create FindMeFood
meteor add telerik:kendo-ui-core-fiori-theme
```

Then I modified `FindMeFood.html`:

```
<head>
    <title>FindMeFood</title>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="where">Where</label>
    <select id="where" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select where...">
        <option>McDonalds</option>
        <option>Burger King</option>
        <option>Wendy's</option>
        <option>Five Guys</option>
        <option>KFC</option>
        <option>Taco Bell</option>
        <option>Pizza Hut</option>
        <option>Papa Johns</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Finally modified `FindMeFood.js`:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    $("#where").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
}
```

And absolutely nothing happened. I ended up with a standard multiple-select box when I started up `Meteor` and visited the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with  at this point, just use a

On `meteor version 1.0.4 or >`

```
 if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.body.onRendered(function(){
      $("#where").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
    })
  }
```

Meteor `1.0.4 or less`

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
   Template.body.rendered = function(){
    $("#where").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
    }
  }
```

Why the `rendered function()`? with the rendered function, you ensure that the code runs when the DOM is ready, in this case the `#where select`

Comment: Sorry, I was busy with my dayjob all this week and didn't have a chance to return to this side project until just now (yay for the weekend). Anyways, your solution seems to be the simpler of the two, not requiring me to create templates that I would only ever use once. So I marked it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The meteor is client method is probably run before your HTML is rendered on the client side.

Try doing this, it's working just fine:

1. Introduce a named template in your `.html` file:

   ```
   <head>
     <title>FindMeFood</title>
   </head>

   <body>
     {{> kendo}}
   </body>

   <template name="kendo">
       <label for="where">Where</label>
       <select id="where" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select where...">
           <option>McDonalds</option>
           <option>Burger King</option>
           <option>Wendy's</option>
           <option>Five Guys</option>
           <option>KFC</option>
           <option>Taco Bell</option>
           <option>Pizza Hut</option>
           <option>Papa Johns</option>
       </select>
   </template>
   ```
2. Add an `onRendered` function to that template (in your js code):

   ```
   if (Meteor.isClient) {
     Template.kendo.onRendered(function () {
       $("#where").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
     });
   }
   ```
3. Have fun selecting multiple locations.

Comment: This appears to be a valid solution but involved creating a template which I would only ever use a single time, so I went with the other proposed solution. Still, +1 for your effort. Thanks!

Comment: I agree that the other solution is more general.